# React Component not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am building [this react tutorial][1] but get stuck at the beginning because my react components are not being recognized.
Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.scss';
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import MovieDetails from "./components/MovieDetails/MovieDetails";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import PageNotFound from "./components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound";



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
     <Router>
     <Header></Header>
      <Routes>
          
          <Route path="/"  component= {Home} />
          <Route path="/movie/:imdbID" component={MovieDetails}/>
          <Route element={PageNotFound}/>
          
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
     </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Basically, it recognizes the imported components but it does not display them in the correct yellow font color. Also, when I run the app only the footer and the header and footer are present. None of the routes work.

Here is the basic Home, Header, and footer component respectively.

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  console.log("hello");
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

```
import React from 'react'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>Header</div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

```
import React from 'react'

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div>Footer</div>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "movie-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions at once. Your routes not working and your yellow colour not showing up appears to be completely different problems.

Comment: I can't see any code which would make anything yellow. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You haven't told us what version of react-router-dom you are using … but I bet it is a different one to what the tutorial you didn't include a link to is based on. Always check the documentation for the version of the library you are using when a third-party tutorial doesn't work.

Comment: can you also share snippets of your package.json file

Comment: element={}, inside element, this needs to be element={<PageNotFound />} something that returns JSX as for react-router-dom v6

Answer (score 0):

Check your React router version, the tutorial seems to be old, and those are deprecated components. this may help
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

check your packag.json and chose the best method for the version you are using.